# How can I properly clip a shapefile to get the section I want using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, clip, topography

I've tried the other "how to clip" instructions here, but consistently get an empty shapefile from the clip.

QGIS Version: 2.4.0-Chugiak

OS: MacOS 10.10

Input File: San Diego (South Map) 1999 Topo (2' intervals) ([1 GB Download Link](http://rdw.sandag.org/file_store/Topography/Topo_1999_2Ft_SD.ZIP))

I've assigned the same CRS from the San Diego Vector Layer to the polygon clipping mask.

Here is a screen capture of my process:

**[QGIS Vector Clipping Path Producing Empty File](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkyqjzYOmAI)**

Hopefully someone can point out where I'm going wrong with this process.

Comment: from your video (very helpful to see) you need to stop editing and save your polygon file. then clip should work.

Comment: Hey @Mapperz, thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and no luck. Still getting the empty file shape.

Comment: Thanks, @Mapperz, that helped. If you want, post an answer with those steps and I'll vote it as the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Please **DO** **NOT** use `Set CRS for Layer` if you want to reproject a vector layer to another CRS. This will corrupt your data, because it does not recalculate any coordinates.

Use Rightclick `Save As ...` under a different file name and different CRS.

You better set the layer back to the previous CRS, or delete it and reload a fresh copy.